# Unexpected result comparing strings with `==`

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

I have two vectors:

```r
a = strsplit("po","")[[1]]
[1] "p" "o"

b = strsplit("polo","")[[1]]
[1] "p" "o" "l" "o"
```

I'm trying to compare them using `==`.
Unfortunately, `a==b` gives an unexpected result.

```r
a==b
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

While I expect to have:

```r
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
```

So, what is causing this? and how can one achieve the expected result?

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the last element of both vectors is the same as changing `b` to e.g. `polf` does give the expected result, and also because setting `b` to `pooo` gives `TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` and not `TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`.

**Edit**

In other words, I'd expect missing elements (when lengths differ) to be passed as nothing (only `""` seems to give `TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE`, `NA` and `NULL` give different results).

```r
c("p","o","","")==c("p","o","l","o")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: What is "l" and "o" comparing to in order to give  `FALSE`?

Comment: @jpdugo17 I edited my answer to make it more clear. I'd like "l" and "o" to be compared to nothing, in a way, so basically always returning `F`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem you've encountered here is due to recycling (not the eco-friendly kind). When applying an operation to two vectors that requires them to be the same length, R often automatically recycles, or repeats, the shorter one, until it is long enough to match the longer one. Your unexpected results are due to the fact that R recycles the vector `c("p", "o")` to be length 4 (length of the larger vector) and essentially converts it to `c("p", "o", "p", "o")`. If we compare `c("p", "o", "p", "o")` and `c("p", "o", "l", "o")` we can see we get the unexpected results of above:

```
c("p", "o", "p", "o") == c("p", "o", "l", "o")
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

It's not exactly clear to me why you would expect the result to be `TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE`, as it's somewhat of an ambiguous comparison to compare a length-2 vector to a length-4 vector, and recycling the length-2 vector (which is what R is doing) seems to be the most reasonable default aside from throwing an error.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. I'd like "l" and "o" to be compared to nothing, in a way, so basically always returning `F`.

Answer (score 6):

To get the result shown in OP we may put the two vectors in a `list`, adapt their `length`s to `max`imum `lengths` (by adding `NA's`) and test if the comparison is `%in% TRUE`.

```
list(a, b) |>
  (\(.) lapply(., `length<-`, max(lengths(.))))() |>
  (\(.) do.call(\(x, y, ...) (x == y) %in% TRUE, .))()
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`

---

*Data:*

```
a <- c("p", "o")
b <- c("p", "o", "l", "o")
```

Answer (score 4):

We may create a function to pad space  (`stringr::str_pad`) on the `right` if any of the strings have less number of characters before the `strsplit`

```
checkStrings <- function(s1, s2) {
   n1 <- nchar(s1)
   n2 <- nchar(s2)
   if(n1 != n2) {
      n <- max(n1, n2)
     i1 <- which.min(c(n1, n2))
     if(i1 == 1) {
       s1 <- stringr::str_pad(s1, width = n, pad = " ", side = "right")
      } else {
      s2 <- stringr::str_pad(s1, width = n, pad = " ", side = "right")
      }
    }
   s1v <- strsplit(s1, "")[[1]]
   s2v <- strsplit(s2, "")[[1]]
   return(s1v == s2v)
   
}
```

-testing

```
> checkStrings(str1, str2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "po"
str2 <- "polo"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve the problem is to create a vector of `length(b)` and `replace` the first values with `a`:

```r
a <- replace(character(length(b)), seq(a), a)
a
# [1] "p" "o" ""  ""
```

Then we can appropriately compare the two vectors using `==`:

```r
a==b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

`character(length(b))` creates a vector of `""` of `length(b)`. `vector(,length(b))` is another option, but it creates a vector of `FALSE` instead.

If one wants to do it over two or more strings, a possible function is:

```r
matchLength = function(strings){
  l = lapply(strings,\(x) strsplit(x,"")[[1]])
  larger = which.max(lengths(l))
  lapply(l, function(x) replace(character(length(l[[larger]])), seq(x), x))
}
```

Which gives the desired output:

```r
strings=c("po","polo","polka")
matchLength(strings)

# [[1]]
# [1] "p" "o" ""  ""  "" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "p" "o" "l" "o" "" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "p" "o" "l" "k" "a"
```